Why model instance is not being supplied to `ModelForm` inside a `DeleteView`
With Django 5.0.2, let's start with a simple model:
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

I want to do some form validation within ModelForm to determine whether or not the deletion should happen inside DeleteView. Simply put, I think the form is already capable of showing non-field errors and I want to avoid using messages.error() to sending back an error message.
So I started with ModelForm:
from django.forms import ModelForm


class DeleteBookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = []

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if not self.deletable():
            self.add_error(None, 'This object can not be deleted')

    def deletable(self) -> bool:
        # do some evaluation on Book here
        book = self.instance
        if book.title == 'delete me please':
            return True
        else:
            return False

and then the DeleteView:
from django.views.generic import DeleteView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class DeleteBookView(DeleteView):
    model = Book
    form_class = DeleteBookForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object.delete()
        messages.success(self.request, 'The object has been deleted successfully.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

But self.instance appears to be None inside DeleteBookForm.deletable(). Indicating that the Book model instance is not being supplied/inserted to the ModelForm when it is being created. I believe this is not the case with UpdateView.
Spent some time reading, I found this code on BaseDeleteView.post() (DeleteView's parent). Note that it is indeed doesn't insert the object to the form:
class BaseDeleteView(DeletionMixin, FormMixin, BaseDetailView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

Eventually, what I did to make it work is by manually inserting the instance when the form is created:
class DeleteBookView(DeleteView):
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        # insert instance so it can be read inside the form
        return self.form_class(
            instance=self.object,
            **self.get_form_kwargs()
        )

Again, the model instance is being supplied by default in UpdateView.
So my questions are:

Why the model instance is not being supplied by default on DeleteView?
Is it wrong to do model instance evaluation using ModelForm on DeleteView? I'm not sure, but I felt like Form is the most logical way to place model instance evaluation rather than on a View, for example.


The form in a DeleteView does not take the instance, it is actually only used to make sure a POST/DELETE request is used.

You only need to mix in the ModelFormMixin [Django-doc], that will thus pass the object to the form:
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import ModelFormMixin


class DeleteBookView(SuccessMessageMixin, ModelFormMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Book
    form_class = DeleteBookForm
    success_message = 'The object has been deleted successfully.'
By default, the DeleteView works with a FormMixin, it thus does not passes the object as model. Usually because the form is more a confirmation, perhaps with a checkbox, not something instance related.

Is it wrong to do model instance evaluation using ModelForm on DeleteView?

It might make more sense to limit the queryset, such that is simply not possible to go to the page where such object is removed, like:
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin


class DeleteBookView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Book
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(title='delete me please')
    success_message = 'The object has been deleted successfully.'
So now it can simply not even retrieve such Book, wich is typically more robust than validating the object through the form.

When importing a form, FormMixin is used, and the methods used are as follows.

    def get_form_class(self):
        """Return the form class to use."""
        return self.form_class

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        """Return an instance of the form to be used in this view."""
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """Return the keyword arguments for instantiating the form."""
        kwargs = {
            "initial": self.get_initial(),
            "prefix": self.get_prefix(),
        }

        if self.request.method in ("POST", "PUT"):
            kwargs.update(
                {
                    "data": self.request.POST,
                    "files": self.request.FILES,
                }
            )
        return kwargs

https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/edit.py
Object information is not transmitted. If you want to pass and check object information, you should do the following.
def get_form_kwargs(self):
  kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
  kwargs['instance'] = self.object
  return kwargs

